# Open a webpage and click a particular tab

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open a webpage on button click, go to a particular section, traverse across multiple pages upon next button arrow image click.

I have to extract information from this website. The HTML structure of page is:

```
<div>
 <div>
  <table class="A">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td class="B">
      <div class="C">
       <ul id="D" class="E">
        <li id="W" class="T U"></li>
        <li id="X" class="T U "></li>
        <li id="Y" class="T U"><span class="SPANCLASSNAME">HEADER TAB CAPTION</span></li>
        <li id="Z" class="T U"></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>  
 </div>
</div>
```

All the data I need could be under any `li` element. Here I have it under the third `li` element.

```
Private Sub Button_Click()
    Dim IE As Object    
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "URL"

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4

    Set AllSpanElements = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("SPANCLASSNAME")
    For Each span In AllSpanElements
        MsgBox span.innerText
        If span.innerText = "HEADER TAB CAPTION" Then
            MsgBox span.innerText
                span.Click  'DOES NOT WORK. WHAT SHOULD BE THE CODE HERE?
            Exit For
        End If
    Next    
    MsgBox "Operation Completed"
End Sub
```

I am able to open the webpage and the MsgBox displays the text from all the `li` elements and flow reaches till Operation Completed but the click action does not happen.

What code would send the click action to IE?

Comment: Try span.Focus then span.Click

Answer (score 0):

If the span has javascript event attached the below code might do the trick.

```
 span.FireEvent("click()")
```

Comment: No Javascript event is attached to div/table/tr/td/ul/span.

Comment: @Ninja Can you share the link ?

Comment: I had an alternative to use link instead of span. That worked and now i am able to navigate to the tab i need. But yet again, i am stuck. This time i have to modify the drop down value using vbscript to get desired results. The tab i am into, has many div elements and one of those contains a div that has 2 drop down lists(created using div). I have to modify the second drop down list. I am able to get the value from the list but not able to set it. Any idea how should i go forward? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be

```
span.onclick();
// or
span.fireEvent('onclick');
```

(without the semi-colons)

**Added** If it is not a JS attached event, try

```
span.click()
```

Comment: No Javascript event is attached to div/table/tr/td/ul/span.

Comment: i tried span.click which did not work & span.click() OR span.click();  throw syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to test it without knowing the URL, but below is the code I came up with:

```
Public Sub sampleCode()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim AllSpanElements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim spanCounter As Long
Dim targetSpan As HTMLObjectElement

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "URL"
    Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState = READYSTATE_LOADING: Wend
    Set HTMLDoc = .document
End With

Set AllSpanElements = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("li")
For spanCounter = 0 To AllSpanElements.Length - 1
    With AllSpanElements(spanCounter)
        MsgBox (.innerText)
        If .innerText = "HEADER TAB CAPTION" Then
            MsgBox (.innerText)
            .Click
            Exit For
        End If
    End With
Next

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
MsgBox "Operation Completed"

End Sub
```

Hope this helps,
TheSilkCode